# Application event listeners not working on jersey

Tags: jakarta-ee, jersey, wildfly, java-ee-7

I have a jerey(2.26) webapplication. My intent here is to listen for application events such as "application initialized" or "application destroyed" and start|stop external database connection. Which is bascially outlined in here (https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/monitoring_tracing.html). For that I'm using ***ApplicationEventListener*** interface and registering its implemented class ***"MyApplicationEventListener"*** as a provider. Im deploying this on ***wildfly-10.1.0.Final*** and it seems wildfly runtime can recognize ***MyApplicationEventListener*** as a provider.

But no application events were recorded or captured ?

Im using web.xml less deployment. So all my application is annotations based. Below are the code snippets Im using.
Wildfly server log

```
09:17:02,866 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (management-handler-thread - 3) WFLYDR0001: Content added at location /home/kalpa/jeeservers/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/data/content/7a/2241598098ebadae4083289691ad2bd3768097/content
09:17:02,925 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: /butterfly
09:17:03,232 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment butterfly.war (runtime-name: butterfly.war) in 319ms
09:17:03,234 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "butterfly.war" (runtime-name: "butterfly.war")
09:17:05,061 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment butterfly.war
09:17:05,488 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.13.SP1 20160303-1204 for context '/butterfly'
09:17:06,493 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class butterfly.v1.rest.AppConfig
09:17:06,503 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource butterfly.v1.rest.AccountService from Application class butterfly.v1.rest.AppConfig
09:17:06,503 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class butterfly.v1.rest.MyApplicationEventListener from Application class butterfly.v1.rest.AppConfig
09:17:06,511 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /butterfly
09:17:06,543 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 3) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "butterfly.war" with deployment "butterfly.war"
09:17:06,566 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (management-handler-thread - 3) WFLYDR0002: Content removed from location /home/kalpa/jeeservers/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/data/content/8a/1139838573568dcc6e81b42dd00592b4dbb517/content
```

Build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'javax:javaee-api:7.0'
    compile 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.5.0'
    compile 'javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.26'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.26-b03'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.26'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.26'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-moxy:2.13'
    compile 'org.json:json:20160810'
    testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.10'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+'
}
```

Application class (I have used jersey's ResourceConfig as well. But no luck)

```
@ApplicationPath(value = "/apiHub")
public class AppConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {

        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        // register root resource
        classes.add(AccountService.class);
        classes.add(MyApplicationEventListener.class);
        return classes;

    }

    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        // Enable Tracing support.
        properties.put(ServletProperties.JAXRS_APPLICATION_CLASS, "butterfly.v1.rest.AppConfig.class");
        properties.put(ServerProperties.APPLICATION_NAME, "Butterfly");
        properties.put(ServerProperties.TRACING, "ALL");
        properties.put(ServerProperties.MONITORING_ENABLED, true);
        properties.put(ServerProperties. MONITORING_STATISTICS_ENABLED, true);
        properties.put(ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES, "butterfly.v1.rest");
        return properties;

    }
}
```

Application event listener class

```
public class MyApplicationEventListener implements ApplicationEventListener {
    private volatile int requestCnt = 0;

    @Override
    public void onEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        switch (event.getType()) {
            case INITIALIZATION_FINISHED:
                System.out.println("Application "+ event.getResourceConfig().getApplicationName()+ " was initialized.");
            break;
            case DESTROY_FINISHED:
                System.out.println("Application "+ event.getResourceConfig().getApplicationName() + "destroyed.");
            break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Default case");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RequestEventListener onRequest(RequestEvent requestEvent) {
        requestCnt++;
        System.out.println("Request " + requestCnt + " started.");
        // return the listener instance that will handle this request.
        return new MyRequestEventListener(requestCnt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure Jersey is being used and not Wildfly's JAX-RS implementation, RESTEasy? The latter does not support this Jersey feature. From the log you posted, it looks like RESTEasy is being used.

Comment: You can search for articles on how to disable RESTEasy in Wildfly, or you can try to use a Jersey specific configuration, namely configuring the ServletContainer in the web.xml. See the docs for Jersey https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet

Comment: Alternatively, stick to the WildFly JAX-RS implementation and investigate the monitoring features that it provides for you by default.